# Vanilla CentOS: Do we need the ElRepo repository?

Tags: centos, kernel, yum

I have a CentOS SFTP server which is critical for my company's operations. Currently, the server is running on a version of the Linux Kernel in which a vulnerability has been found:

`Linux 3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64`

I am trying to update CentOS with YUM, but it does not mention any missing update on the system. Upon research, a lot of articles out there point to the idea of adding the ElRepo repository for Kernel updates.

I wonder however why is this necessary? I know this is a well respected repository and all that, but if possible I would really rather stuck with the CentOS repositories only.

Shouldn't CentOS have the Kernel updates within its own repositories?

So to be objective on my question: How can I update my CentOS kernel in a 100% official way to get rid of this vulnerability? https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-cr-announce/2020-October/012745.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Community Enterprise Linux Repository (ELRepo) focuses on kmod driver packages to enhance hardware support in EL6, EL7, and EL8 (including display, filesystem, hwmon, network, and storage drivers). Newer kernels are also available. Follow the ELRepo Home Page to install the elrepo-release package and import the GPG key.

If you are not specifically making use of a kernel mod/update (coming from ELREPO for example) then it quickly gets hard to justify in a business/legal sense why it would be used not to mention it's probably not addressing the actual vulnerability.   For https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2020:4060 if that's not addressed in an update from ELREPO (where they focus on *enhanced hardware support*) or anyone else then their update is doing you no good; don't simply grab an update from a 3rd party simply because it's an "update" unless it actually addresses the problem at hand.  You have to look into it.

> So to be objective on my question: How can I update my CentOS kernel in a 100% official way to get rid of this vulnerability?  Vanilla CentOS: Do we need the ElRepo repository?  I have a CentOS SFTP server which is critical for my company's operations.

- Have **only** the official CentOS repository [repositories] active on your system.
- Have GPG enabled in `/etc/yum.conf` to make use of that protection mechanism.
- **only** get the kernel update from the official centos repository, that is created upon installation [and automatic activation of the free distribution] of CentOS linux.

It of course depends on what you really mean by *vanilla* but no you would not need/require ELREPO or even EPEL for just SFTP if that's the server's only function.  Having *critical for my company's operations* then in my opinion you should only be using the official centos repo, and not even epel or elrepo unless those address some specific business/security thing.  Wwhat was already said: *it take some time for CentOS maintainers to take RedHat sources and build them for CentOS* is true.  Kernel updates, especially going from RHEL/CentOS 7.8 to 7.9 for example, takes time on the CentOS side.  CentOS comes from RHEL, RHEL will always release things first, then the CentOS folks get their hands on it and make it happen but there is a delay.  That's the price of using a free distribution.  Either unplug your CentOS server and wait for the update to come out if it's that severe would be the *official* way.  If that delay is unacceptable then your company should be using a paid for RHEL subscription and not free CentOS.

> Upon research a lot of articles out there point to the idea of adding the ElRepo repository for Kernel updates.  I wonder however why is this necessary?

Bottom of centos repo link below: *An example of what NOT to do, please do NOT follow such examples. Use a critical eye and some thought to see what is being proposed before adding to (and possibly breaking) your system.*  I'm taking that a little out of context, since ELREPO specifically is a good 3rd party repo it has it's place, but it's the principle of it.

https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, it take some time for CentOS maintainers to take RedHat sources and build them for CentOS.

Today, I have received a notification that a kernel update 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7 is available. So, I guess you can install it. Maybe it takes some time for the update to reach servers near you, and you have to wait some more day.

[Here](https://linux.oracle.com/switch/centos/) is a chart that shows how long does it take for CentOS to publish fixes. [With changed support for CentOS](https://blog.centos.org/2020/12/future-is-centos-stream/) I would recommend you to start looking for an alternative. With CentOS 7 you will receive security updates until 2024, but with CentOS 8 only until end of 2021.